# Mysql - IMPALA query help needed

Tags: mysql, impala

I have one table in hive `table1`. I am using impala to fetch data from table

```
table1
------
name, amount
```

where values of table are

```
test1, 10
test1, 15
test1, 30

test2, 30
test2, 40
test2, 50

test3, 30
test3, 40
test3, 50
```

Now I have to fetch data from table1 such that, it fetch data for all `name (test1, test2, test3)`  `but gives only top 2 records based on amount for each name`.

```
Can it possible in IMPALa or even in MYSQL?
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: is the occurrence count of `name` field is limited to 3 or is it dynamic???

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Impala 2.0 or greater, you can use [analytic functions](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/cloudera-impala/latest/topics/impala_analytic_functions.html) to accomplish this task:

```
SELECT name, amount
FROM (SELECT name, amount, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY amount DESC) AS pos
      FROM table1) t
WHERE pos < 3;
```

If you must use MySQL, it appears that you can fake window functions using [user-defined variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html), as demonstrated in [another question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333665/mysql-rank-function).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `regexp_extract` to get the limits of concatenated amounts. `{1,1}` will give you the top 2. `{1,49}` will give you the top 50, etc.

For example (top 2):

```
>select name, regexp_extract(group_concat(cast(amount as string),','), '^(([0-9]+,)<b>{1,1}</b>[0-9]+|[0-9]+)',0) as top_two_amount from (select name, amount from table1 order by name, amount desc) t group by name;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a difficult time understanding your question, but if I understand you correctly, you're trying to get a listing of all the amounts by name. If that's the case, in MySQL, this is pretty simple:

```
  SELECT name, GROUP_CONCAT( amount ) AS amounts FROM table1 GROUP BY name ;
```

This will give you a row for each name with all the amounts associated with that name.